# What is the difference between these 2 arrays

Tags: c++, c

How are these two declarations different?

`uint8_t xyz[3];`

and

`uint8_t xyz[3]={0,0,0};`

Application type is use as a buffer for register data on an imu. Wouldn’t they both initialize an empty array with a size of max size of 4? Excuse my formatting I am on mobile.

Comment: Where have you got "max size of 4" from?

Comment: @George It's incredible how confused newbies get by the array indexes start at zero rule. They can invent all sorts of weird complications based on this.

Comment: @george also it can be confusing that `xyz[3]` has different meaning depending on context, once `3` is number of elements otherwise it is the index. One is so much used to it that it takes quite some questions to read to realize that it isnt natural at all.

Comment: Do not tag a question both C and C++ unless it specifically involves a comparison or interaction between both languages. Doing so has caused confusion as some answers speak only to one language without stating which.

Comment: Please don't edit your answer so that it invalidates answers already posted

Comment: well @EricPostpischil i got the answer i was looking for, so looks like it worked out before you closed my post..i tagged c++ because i am also using that alongside the C but thanks breh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Notice:** The question is tagged with both C and C++. These have a lot in common but are different languages. This answer was written as an answer for C. However, a small comment regarding C++ has been added in the end.

The "C answer":

> How are these two declarations different?

Well, it's a bit strange to state the obvious but here it is:

The first statement is without an initializer while the second has an explicit initializer.

Hmmm... I think your real question is this:

> Wouldn’t they both initialize an empty array with a max size of 4?

There is an interresting misunderstanding here: "... **an empty array with a max size** ..."

In C there is no such thing as an **empty** array. Once an array is created, it's size is fixed, i.e. always the same. An array can't hold 2 elements at one point in time and then 3 elements later and 1 element later and so on. Arrays doesn't work like that - the number of elements is fixed.

So if you do

```
uint8_t xyz[3];
```

you have an array with **3 elements** rigth from the start and as long as the array exists.

Your question said 4 elements which is wrong. There are 3 elements and you can access them as `xyz[0]`, `xyz[1]` and `xyz[2]`. Accessing `xyz[3]` is **illegal**.

So maybe you really wanted to ask:

> Wouldn’t they both create an array with **3 elements initialized to zero** ?

For sure the second will due to use of an explicit initializer.

For the first it depends where the code is placed. If it's inside a function, the array **will not** be initialized to zero. If it's outside a function it **will** be initialized to zero. Like:

```
// Global variables
uint8_t xyzA[3];          // Will be zero initialized
uint8_t xyzB[3]={0,0,0};  // Will be zero initialized

void foo()
{
    // Local variables
    uint8_t xyzC[3];          // Will NOT be zero initialized
    uint8_t xyzD[3]={0,0,0};  // Will be zero initialized
    ...
    ...
}
```

**Note:** The use of global variables (aka variables with static storage duration) is something that should be avoid in all most all cases. Always prefer local variables (aka variables with automatic storage duration) or - in case of large arrays - dynamic allocated variables.

BTW:

The code

```
uint8_t xyzD[3]={0,0,0};
```

can also be written

```
uint8_t xyzD[3]={0};
```

As long as there is just a single initializer, all remaining elements will be "default initialized" which for `uint8_t` means: Initialized to zero.

**Finally - for C++:**

The above holds for C++ as well. However, it's worth to mention a few special things for C++.

Code like `int arr[3];` is legal C++ code but in modern C++ it's rarely used. The better alternatives are `std::array` and - even more common - `std::vector`.

`std::array` is fixed size - just like the C-style array. `std::vector` is variable size. The size of a vector can increase as elements are added and shrink as elements are erased.

Comment: unfortunately the last paragraph can be misunderstood as global arrays being "nice", nevertheless nice answer

Comment: @idclev463035818 Thanks for the feedback :-) I've added a note below the code to stress that global variables are "bad". Hope it improves the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and for clearing up some of my misconceptions. I’m self-taught and don’t really have anyone to run questions off of in person, so there are definitely small, critical things I miss. But the different scope inside or outside the function sounds to be the issue I was having so ty for clearing that up and excuse my ignorance. I’m trying lol

Answer (score 1):

The first one doesn't get initialised (unless it's at file scope, or static).

And of course the size is three not four, and the size is fixed.

Comment: The question is tagged C and C++, and this answer does not state which language it is for.

Answer (score 0):

This buffer `uint8_t xyz[3];` is uninitialized, it may contains garbage values.
Size of array of [3] is always 3 elements.

Comment: The question is tagged C and C++, and this answer does not state which language it is for.

Answer (score 0):

> How are these two declarations different?
>
> ```
> uint8_t xyz[3];
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> uint8_t xyz[3]={0,0,0};
> ```

The first (since C++11) default-initialises the array.  The meaning of that depends on where the declaration is placed.

- If the definition is at file scope then default initialisation means the elements are zero-initialised
- If the definition is in a function block (as is - i.e. the declaration is of an array with automatic storage duration) then its elements are uninitialised.   This means their values are indeterminate, and accessing their values gives undefined behaviour.   To avoid that undefined behaviour, it is necessary to initialise the elements (e.g. set them to a known valid value) before accessing their value.

The second form ensures all elements are initialised to zero.

> Application type is use as a buffer for register data on an imu. Wouldn’t they both initialize an empty array with a max size of 4?

No.  On two counts.

First, there is no such thing as an empty array in C++.

Second, both the arrays are defined with exactly three elements, which can be accessed as `xyz[0]`, `xyz[1]`, and `xyz[2]`.   Note that array indexing starts at zero in C++, so an array with three elements has elements with indices `0`, `1`, and `2` but NOT `3`.

Accessing any elements other than those three (e.g. accessing `xyz[3]`) gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: thanks, cleared up a lot of small details i was missing! not a trained programmer so my skills are HEAVILY still a work in progress lol

Answer (score -2):

`uint8_t xyz [3]` is an uninitialized static array, which means that in that memory area you will find garbage values if you want to access it. For example `xyz[0]` will be `-958643483` something like that. (Just some garbage)

`uint8_t xyz [3] = {0,0,0}` is an initialized static array, which means that in that memory area you will find the values `{0,0,0}`. For example `xyz[0]` will be `0`.